# How to change React Native Android's default text color to black with Android Manifest?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

After ejecting my app from expo to react native default text color has light black color, i want to change it to black, i tried many times, but it dont changes, do you have any idea how to do it?

my AndroidManifest:

```
<application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Styles:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FF00FF</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
  </style>
```

and after changing textColor it still have same light black color..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line to the layout file:

```
<TextView  style="@style/TextColor" />
```

Comment: Yeah, but I have so many text in my app and by default color was black by expo, i would like to change it globally if there is possibility